# How to properly compare signed vs unsigned ints

Tags: c++

How would it better to compare signed vs unsigned ? (probably a duplicate but I cannot find the proper answer)

```
unsigned i = -1
int j = -1
...
if ((int)i != j) j= (int) j
```

or

```
if (int(i) != j) j=int(i)
```

does it make a difference ? I am using the former, but I see that in some extreme cases the j returns an nonphysically large number in my code.

Comment: unsigned can't be less than 0. So the -1 assignment on `i` results in max-unsigned int as value

Comment: thanks for the comment - in any case, if `i=0` in the first place, what would be the proper syntax to compare them ?

Comment: There's no difference in your comparisons, and both potentially invoke implementation defined behavior. If possible, don't mix signed and unsigned in the first place. (My recommendation: Stay away from unsigned ints unless you are doing bit magic, but that's somewhat disputed.)

Comment: For a 32-bit `int` (which is the most used these days) the value `-1` is equal to the unsigned value `0xffffffff`. Read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to understand why.

Comment: As for your question, there is not difference (in this case), both are doing [an explicit (also called C-style) cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) of the variable `i`. If instead of `int` you had a class type instead, then there would be a difference, especially if `i` was an object of another class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it depends on the ranges of the values.

If the signed value can ever be less than 0 you should cast the unsigned to the signed one.

On the other hand when the value of the unsigned can be more than max signed you should cast the signed to the unsigned.

If both are true you should use a bigger type.

Also just for style `static_cast<int>(i)` looks better.

If you are not sure about the ranges, check them before you cast the type manually or use something like `boost::numeric_cast`